# Can I use the map function to implement merging two list as one in Common Lisp?

Tags: list, dictionary, common-lisp

There are two list like:

```
(setf l1 '((1 . 1) (2 . 2) (3 . 3)  (4 . 4) (5 . 5)))
(setf l2 '(2  22  4  44  6 66))    ;; this is a alist
```

I want to merge these two list to one like:

```
((1 . 1) (2 . 22) (3 . 3)  (4 . 44) (5 . 5)  (6 . 66))
```

I can use some `Set` function to do like `intersection` and `set-difference`.

But I want to implement that using `map` function without iterator function like `do`, `loop` , I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It's not clear what your merging algorithm is.  Your second list is actually a property list;  the corresponding alist would be `((2 . 22) (4 . 44) (6 . 66))`.  In the merged result, why is `2` mapped to `22` as opposed to `2`?  What's the merge supposed to be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the lists, this does not look like a *merge* but like an *update*: you want to update the data in `l1` with the updates specified in `l2`.

```
(defun update (target updates)
  "Returns a copy of the alist TARGET where the values are updated according
to the plist UPDATES."
  (mapcar (lambda (assoc)
            (let ((update (getf updates (car assoc) :not-found)))
              (if (eq update :not-found)
                  assoc
                  (cons (car assoc) update))))
          target))
```

If `updates` gets bigger than a few tens of elements, you should first transform it to a data structure that better scales with respect to random lookups.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert `l2` to a bona fide alist:

```
(setq l3 (loop for (a b) on l2 by #'cddr collect (cons a b)))
==> ((2 . 22) (4 . 44) (6 . 66))
```

Next you can [merge](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_merge.htm) them:

```
(setq l4 (merge 'list l1 l3 #'< :key #'car))
==> ((1 . 1) (2 . 2) (2 . 22) (3 . 3) (4 . 4) (4 . 44) (5 . 5) (6 . 66))
```

Now you can [remove the duplicates](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm) (BEWARE! unnecessary quadratic complexity!):

```
(setq l5 (delete-duplicates l4 :key #'car))
==> ((1 . 1) (2 . 22) (3 . 3) (4 . 44) (5 . 5) (6 . 66))
```

1. I don't think you can do this with a simple map.
2. The most efficient implementation will use a single hand-crafted loop, not system functions.